# Export Excel With GridLines

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel

I have below mentioned code to export data into excel

Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;

```
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
         "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        Table tb = new Table();
        GridView gv=new GridView();

        tb.GridLines = gv.GridLines;

        tb.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        TableRow tr1 = new TableRow();
        TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
        cell1.Controls.Add(BalanceSheetListControl2);
        tr1.Cells.Add(cell1);
        tb.Rows.Add(tr1);
        tb.RenderControl(hw);

        //style to format numbers to string
        string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; backgroud-color:transparent !important; } </style>";
        Response.Write(style);


        System.IO.StringReader writer = new System.IO.StringReader(sw.ToString());
       string s=string.Empty;
       string readString = string.Empty;
       bool StartFlag = false;
       StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
        while((readString=writer.ReadLine())!=null)
        {
           // readString = writer.ReadLine().Trim();
            s = readString;
            Regex search_string = new Regex("<div.*?>([^<]+)</div>");
            Match match = search_string.Match(s);
            string section = match.Groups[1].Value.ToString();
            if (section.Trim()=="-")
            {
                s = s.Replace(">-<", "><div align='right'>-</div><");
               // s = s.Replace("-", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;");
            }

            if (readString.Trim().Contains("main") || readString.Trim().Contains("column c"))
            {

                s=s+"</td><td>";
            }

            build.Append(s);

        }

        Response.Output.Write(build.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
```

I have to show grid lines in Excel for that I used following code

```
        GridView gv=new GridView();
        tb.GridLines = gv.GridLines;
```

after using upper code excel will generate only vertical grid lines, I also need horizontal line  can any one please help me how to achieve this?
Thanks in Advance

**for reference I have attached the Image of my current Excel**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this code its works for me.

```
 public static void ExportWithBorder(string fileName, GridView gv)
   {
       HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
       HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader(
           "content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));
       HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";           

       using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
       {
           using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
           {
               //  Create a form to contain the grid
               Table table = new Table();

               //  add the header row to the table
               if (gv.HeaderRow != null)
               {
                   GridViewExportUtil.PrepareControlForExport(gv.HeaderRow);
                   gv.HeaderRow.Style.Add("border", "solid 1px #c1d8f1");
                   table.Rows.Add(gv.HeaderRow);
               }

               //  add each of the data rows to the table
               foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
               {
                   GridViewExportUtil.PrepareControlForExport(row);
                   row.Style.Add("border", "solid 1px #c1d8f1");
                   table.Rows.Add(row);
               }

               //  add the footer row to the table
               if (gv.FooterRow != null)
               {
                   GridViewExportUtil.PrepareControlForExport(gv.FooterRow);
                   gv.FooterRow.Style.Add("border", "solid 1px #c1d8f1");
                   table.Rows.Add(gv.FooterRow);
               }

               //  render the table into the htmlwriter                    
               table.RenderControl(htw);

               //  render the htmlwriter into the response
               HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sw.ToString());
               HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
           }
       }
   }

    /// <summary>
    /// Replace any of the contained controls with literals
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="control"></param>
    private static void PrepareControlForExport(Control control)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < control.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
            Control current = control.Controls[i];
            if (current is LinkButton)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as LinkButton).Text));
            }
            else if (current is ImageButton)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as ImageButton).AlternateText));
            }
            else if (current is HyperLink)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as HyperLink).Text));
            }
            else if (current is DropDownList)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Text));
            }
            else if (current is CheckBox)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as CheckBox).Checked ? "True" : ""));
            }
            else if (current is TextBox)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as TextBox).Text));
            }
            if (current.HasControls())
            {
                GridViewExportUtil.PrepareControlForExport(current);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @DhavalPatel Do not forgot to accept the right answer so that it will also be helpful for others